# How to use the 'scroll' and 'max' options in Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need help with aucomplete of the jquery.

```
jQuery("#PeopleName").autocomplete(
                                   {source:["name1","name2","..."],
                                    minLength:2,
                                    max:10,
                                    scroll:true});
```

The 'scroll' and 'max' are not working.
I am use jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js.
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Is this the jQuery-ui auto complete or some other auto complete?

Comment: The autocomplete working but the scroll and max not working.

Comment: jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js

Comment: Have a look at [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). I do not see any `scroll` and `max` properties documented in options, events or methods.

Comment: Look at this site: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery)

Comment: The first answer on this question probably refers to an old version of jQuery UI. I think the two options you mentioned are not present in latest version. You might get luck with an older version. Or... if you can edit you question and tell exactly what you want, perhaps someone can post code (or hack) that works in current version.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. I found the code in [jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#maxheight)

```
<style>
       .ui-autocomplete {
            max-height: 200px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
            padding-right: 20px;
        } 
</style>

<script>
jQuery("#PeopleName").autocomplete({
                                   source:["name1","name2","..."],
                                   minLength:2
                                   });

</script>
```

This is working.